# How do I translate VB.NET's CType() to C#?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, casting

I have this code segment in VB.NET:

```
CType(pbImageHolder.Image, Bitmap).SetPixel(curPoint.X, curPoint.Y, Color.Purple)
```

What is appropriate code in C#?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In VB.Net `CType(object, type)` casts an object to a specific type.

There are two ways to accomplish this in C#:

```
Bitmap image = pbImageHolder.Image as Bitmap;
image.SetPixel(curPoint.X, curPoint.Y, Color.Purple);
```

or

```
Bitmap image = (Bitmap)(pbImageHolder.Image);
image.SetPixel(curPoint.X, curPoint.Y, Color.Purple);
```

Comment: 1) First option you provided strongly requires null-checking; `as` isn't intended for use cases without null-checking of result and can't be positioned as direct equivalent of VB `CType` operator; 2) The second option has unnecessary brackets, see answer to your comment below. So, down-voted, especially for `as` negligent usage.

Comment: As Dennis said, don't use `as` in cases like this. It might lead to a non-informative `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: @Dennis is a good advice but you don't need to downvote only because of that. The answer is still useful

Comment: `CType` does not cast an object, it converts it. `DirectCast` or `TryCast` are the casting operations. For example, `Dim i As Integer = CType("1", Integer)` is valid, but `Dim i As Integer = DirectCast("1", Integer)` is not

Answer (score 10):

```
((Bitmap)pbImageHolder.Image).SetPixel(curPoint.X, curPoint.Y, Color.Purple)
```

Comment: With `((Bitmap)pbImageHolder.Image)` your trying to cast pbImageHolder to Bitmap, which probably won't work. The following will cast the image: `(Bitmap)(pbImageHolder.Image)`

Comment: @DennisTraub: you're wrong, see C# language specification, section 7.3.1 "Operator precedence and associativity" (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=199552). Member access operator "." has precedence over cast operator, so, expressions like `(TypeWichCastTo)variable.Member` will evaluate this way: 1) access `Member` of `variable` first; 2) then cast `Member` to `TypeWichCastTo`.

Answer (score 2):

Hi this is the code after conversion VB to C# code:

```
((Bitmap)pbImageHolder.Image).SetPixel(curPoint.X, curPoint.Y, Color.Purple);
```

And if you want code conversion from VB to C# and vice verse go through the following link: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Answer (score -1):

I'm surprised that none of the answers on this subject are correct so I decided to post here. You can verify what is going on by decompiling a VB.NET program. The answer depends on the type being converted to.

For reference types:

`Dim value = CType(x, ReferenceType)`

`var value = (ReferenceType)x;`

For structs:

`Dim value = CType(x, StructType)`

`var value = (x != null) ? ((StructType)x) : default(StructType);`

For predefined casts:

`Dim value = CDbl(x)`

`var value = Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToDouble(x)`

Which looks like this:

```
internal static double ToDouble(object Value, NumberFormatInfo NumberFormat)
{
    if (Value == null)
    {
        return 0.0;
    }
    IConvertible convertible = Value as IConvertible;
    if (convertible != null)
    {
        switch (convertible.GetTypeCode())
        {
        case TypeCode.Boolean:
            if (Value is bool)
            {
                return 0 - (((bool)Value) ? 1 : 0);
            }
            return 0 - (convertible.ToBoolean(null) ? 1 : 0);
        case TypeCode.SByte:
            if (Value is sbyte)
            {
                return (sbyte)Value;
            }
            return convertible.ToSByte(null);
        case TypeCode.Byte:
            if (Value is byte)
            {
                return (int)(byte)Value;
            }
            return (int)convertible.ToByte(null);
        case TypeCode.Int16:
            if (Value is short)
            {
                return (short)Value;
            }
            return convertible.ToInt16(null);
        case TypeCode.UInt16:
            if (Value is ushort)
            {
                return (int)(ushort)Value;
            }
            return (int)convertible.ToUInt16(null);
        case TypeCode.Int32:
            if (Value is int)
            {
                return (int)Value;
            }
            return convertible.ToInt32(null);
        case TypeCode.UInt32:
            if (!(Value is uint))
            {
                return convertible.ToUInt32(null);
            }
            return (uint)Value;
        case TypeCode.Int64:
            if (Value is long)
            {
                return (long)Value;
            }
            return convertible.ToInt64(null);
        case TypeCode.UInt64:
            if (!(Value is ulong))
            {
                return convertible.ToUInt64(null);
            }
            return (ulong)Value;
        case TypeCode.Decimal:
            if (Value is decimal)
            {
                return convertible.ToDouble(null);
            }
            return Convert.ToDouble(convertible.ToDecimal(null));
        case TypeCode.Single:
            if (Value is float)
            {
                return (float)Value;
            }
            return convertible.ToSingle(null);
        case TypeCode.Double:
            if (Value is double)
            {
                return (double)Value;
            }
            return convertible.ToDouble(null);
        case TypeCode.String:
            return ToDouble(convertible.ToString(null), NumberFormat);
        }
    }
    throw new InvalidCastException(Utils.GetResourceString("InvalidCast_FromTo", Utils.VBFriendlyName(Value), "Double"));
}
```